# Grails Duplicate Error Messages

Tags: validation, grails, groovy, command-objects

I'm new to grails and I have a problem:

I have this snippet of GSP:

```
<g:form url="[controller:'main',action:'login']"> 
  <label for="name">Usuario:</label><br/> 
  <input type="text" name="name" /><br/> 
  <label for="pass">Password:</label><br/> 
  <input type="password" name="password"/><br/> 
  <input type="submit" value="Login"/><br/> 
  <g:renderErrors bean="${cmd}"/> 
</g:form>
```

The Controller (MainController.groovy) uses a Command Object, here's the code for both:

```
def login = { LoginCommand cmd -> 
  if(cmd.validate()){ 
  redirect(action:'ok') 
  }else{ 
  render(view:'index',model:[cmd:cmd]) 
  } 
  } 

class LoginCommand { 

        String name 
        String password 

        static constraints = { 
                name(blank:false,size:5..10) 
                password(blank:false,size:5..10) 
        } 
}
```

The problem is that when I enter a bad name or pass (blank or outside the range) **it shows me 4 errors, two for the password and two for the username**. They are the same, but duplicated.

I found that creating a method "bool validateCommand(){ name && password }" and replacing it for command.validate() does not throw duplicates, but I want to use the constraints features of Grails to keep things DRY.

Any idea why this happens? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you inject command objects into controller actions, Grails executes `validate()` automatically, so there is no need to call it manually. Try

```
if(!cmd.hasErrors())
```

instead of

```
if(cmd.validate())
```

It seems, that every call to `validate()` adds new (duplicate) errors to the command object. IMHO this shouldn't happen and probably is a bug in Grails. You should consider [reporting](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS) this issue.